# Minable et abominable

Tags: étymologie, adjectifs

Est-ce que *minable* et *abominable* ont la même origine, vu qu'ils sont tous les deux utilisés dans les mêmes « conditions » ?

Comment: Leur sens sont très différents. Cela dit, étant donné leur ressemblance lexicale, s’intéresser à leur étymologie reste légitime.

Comment: Dans quelles "conditions" utiliseriez-vous *minable* et *abominable* de la même manière?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le Wiktionnaire indique des étymologies assez différentes pour [minable](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/minable) et [abominable](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abominable).

Minable:

> Composé de [miner](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/miner#fr-verb) (sens #3) et -able.

Abominable:

> Emprunté au latin *[abominabilis](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abominabilis#la)* (« repoussant, répugnant, détestable »).

Comment: *Abomination/abominable* ne serait-il pas une construction à partir du verbe latin *ominare* avec le préfixe *ab* ? Si oui, l'apparente parenté avec l'étymologie de *minable* est à écarter... à voir.